# ECA (Event Condition Action) Forward Chain Rules in Force.com - Did anyone try before?

Tags: rules-engine

Did anyone try ECA (Event Condition Action) Rules using Visual Force  pages? If yes, can you please state how to implement? Is Java Script library available that can be leveraged in Visual Force pages?

Comment: Are you on LinkedIn user8068?

Comment: What exactly is an ECA Forward Chain? ECA Seems to be mostly database trigger related, so the mention of javascript is quite confusing here.

Comment: I have a requirement where based on certain attribute level values and compound conditions, I need to control the behavior of the VisualForce pages (such as disabling/ enabling, mandatory fields, form field/pick list values etc.) - moreover, these condition sets and action sets should be configurable so that no deployment is required. I hope, I could clarify.

Comment: Example 1 (ECA Rule) – 

{"id": "rule101",
"appliesTo": ["http://mail.yahoo.com/"],
"eventExpression": {"type": "click",
"target": "$X"
},
"condition":[
"$X:HTMLAnchorElement($hrefVal:href)",
"new RegExp(/showMessage\?fid=Inbox/).test($hrefVal)"
],
"actions":["append($X.textContent)"]
}